# Is there any way to avoid storage_os_disk from inheriting tags when creating azurerm_virtual_machine resource using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

storage_os_disk gets tagged in the Azure portal and this isn't necessarily what I want when specifying runbooks per tag, any way to avoid this inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

you can create os disk separately using `azurerm_managed_disk` and then use [this](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html#managed_disk_id-1) to reference that existing disk. You need to use [FromImage](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/managed_disk.html#fromimage) create option for the managed disk.

```
storage_os_disk {
    name              = "myosdisk1"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "Attach"
    managed_disk_id   = "disk_resource_id"
}

resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "test" {
  name                 = "acctestmd"
  location             = "West US 2"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  create_option        = "FromImage"
  image_reference_id   = "platformi_image_resource_id"
  disk_size_gb         = "32"
}
```

Comment: This answer would be improved if it was a complete workable example instead of just links to external resources. As it is it won't be particularly useful if those links die for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll give this a try.